# SSIS SQL Task Parameter mapping

Tags: sql-server, types, ssis

I've a stored procedure which outputs a bit datatype. I'm trying to map the output of the stored procedure to a variable in the SSIS package (@myVar)
I'm running this from within a SSIS package and I'm trying to map the datatypes but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

```
Output from Stored Procedure = bit
SSIS variable type @myVar = boolean
Mapped parameter = what??
```

There is no bit or bool in the tasks drop down menu, the closest is variant_bool which doesn't work, and I can't change the output type of the stored procedure -
 as it is somebody's else's code.
Any Ideas, anyone?

Comment: Did u tried with `Int32` type in variable mapping

Comment: I've faced this. Dont exactly remember...but try `Long` and `Varchar`. Let me know the output

Comment: Yes just use LONG as datatype in your parameter mapping. That will work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Test code**

```
create PROCEDURE dbo.uspGetTrueOrFalse
(
    @CustomerID int,
    @CustomerName nvarchar(101) output,
    @IsItTrueOrFalse bit output
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @CustomerName = 'Red Bicycle Company';
    SET @IsItTrueOrFalse = 1; --Set to true

END;
GO
```

**Setup SQL Tasks**

[image]

**Parameter mapping**
[image]

**Execution status of variables**
[image]

Comment: Thanks plaidDK - That has worked a treat, very much appriciated

Comment: @GrahamReavey Your welcome. Mark it as correct so others can benefit from it. Thank in advance

Comment: @GrahamReavey I notice you have not accepted any of the answers on any of your recent questions, even though your comments indicate that it solved your problem.   If you make it a habit not to accept answers that help you, people will become less inclined to help you in the future.   Help yourself by accepting this answer:  click the checkmark icon near the upper left corner of the answer.   You might want to revisit your past questions to remedy this.

Comment: Hi Tab Alleman, Its not that I'm not accepting them, its more that I'm not sure how to. I've tried voting up replies but I don't have enough 'points' for it to register. I am, however very appreciative of any and all replies